# How to find sum of total value from inner array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fb04fd2e6bb8bc059287c9"), 
    "BillNo" : "Bill_001", 
    "DateP" : "12-12-2015", 
    "Type" : "Cash", 
    "Items" : [
        {
            "id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ItemName" : "cement", 
            "Qty" : "100", 
            "Rate" : "10", 
            "Total" : "1000"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : NumberInt(2), 
            "ItemName" : "steel", 
            "Qty" : "10", 
            "Rate" : "50", 
            "Total" : "500"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : NumberInt(3), 
            "ItemName" : "sand", 
            "Qty" : "1", 
            "Rate" : "1500", 
            "Total" : "1500"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fb05382e6bb8bc059287ca"), 
    "BillNo" : "Bill_002", 
    "DateP" : "12-10-2015", 
    "Type" : "Cash", 
    "Items" : [
        {
            "id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ItemName" : "Paint", 
            "Qty" : "50", 
            "Rate" : "100", 
            "Total" : "5000"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : NumberInt(2), 
            "ItemName" : "Brush", 
            "Qty" : "5", 
            "Rate" : "10", 
            "Total" : "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above collection stores all the purchase details in main document and its Items details storing as inner array of main item.I need to get the result like following by using mongodb; How to find total from inner array in mongodb.

```
Bill_001     1500
Bill_002     5050
```

Comment: All your values of strings. You should fix them since you cannot really add strings together.

Comment: Result will be like Bill_001 -> 3000, Bill_002 -> 5050

Comment: If it is changed to int then how will be the mongo shell?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally in MongoDB you can use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) as both an [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) accumulator and it's new role in adding the members of the provided array:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$BillNo",
       "Total": {
           "$sum": {
               "$sum": {
                  "$map": {
                     "input": "$Items",
                     "as": "item",
                     "in": "$$item.Total"
                  }
               }
           }
       }
   }}
})
```

Or just per document:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "BillNo": { "$first": "$BillNo" },
       "DateP": { "$first" "$DateP" },
       "Type": { "$first": "$Type" }
       "Total": {
           "$sum": {
               "$sum": {
                  "$map": {
                     "input": "$Items",
                     "as": "item",
                     "in": "$$item.Total"
                  }
               }
           }
       }
   }}
})
```

Using the other accumulator of [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/). Of course you could really just [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) With MongoDB 3.2:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
   { "$project": {
       "BillNo": 1,
       "DateP": 1,
       "Type": 1,
       "Total": {
           "$sum": {
              "$map": {
                 "input": "$Items",
                 "as": "item",
                 "in": "$$item.Total"
              }
           }
       }
   }}
})
```

In older versions you still need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array first:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$Items" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$BillNo",
       "Total": {
           "$sum": "$Items.Total"
       }
    }}
])
```

Or if you are only adding per document:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$Items" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "_id",
       "BillNo": { "$first": "$BillNo" },
       "DateP": { "$first": "$DateP" },
       "Type": { "$first": "$Type" },
       "Total": {
           "$sum": "$Items.Total"
       }
    }}
])
```

But only of course once you actually fix the strings to be numeric values.

Ideally you can fix it like this:

```js
var ops = [];

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.Items.forEach(function(item) {
        ops.push({
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id, "Items.id": item.id },
                "update": {
                    "$set": {
                        "Items.$.Qty": parseInt(item.Qty),
                        "Items.$.Rate": parseInt(item.Rate),
                        "Items.$Total": parseInt(item.Total)
                    }
                }
            }        
        });

        // Send batch of updates
        if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
            db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
            ops = [];
        }
    })
});

// Clear any unprocessed updates
if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. working proper. In case if i want to display BillNo, Date, Type.. etc.. along with "Total" then how it will be. I am using $unwind method. plz reply this also

Comment: @Pradeep That is not what your question asks. Welcome to stackoverflow, you get to ask one question at a time here, and when you have another question then [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You are asking to "accumulate" on the value of `"BillNo"`, so this means that values such as `"Type"` of course change per document and are not part of the grouping. You can use other [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/),  but that is not part of your question.